# Ng2-Charts in Angular: Is 'Auto' supported for display property of Axes

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am using ng2-charts and chart.js in Angular, specifically line chart. I am setting the chart options as below

I am setting display property to auto, so that the y-axis is shown only when data mapping to that axis is rendered.
However, when compiling the angular app I am getting an error

error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

I checked chart.js documentation and it says the display property can be boolean or string and 'Auto' is an accepted value.

Why would I be getting compile error if chart.js supports string for display property?

```
import {ChartDataSets, ChartData, ChartOptions} from 'chart.js';
import {Color, BaseChartDirective, Label} from 'ng2-charts';
```

....

```
private lineChartOptions : (ChartOptions) = {
    responsive: true,
    scales:{
      xAxes: [{
        id: 'x-axis-0',
        position: 'bottom'
      }],
      yAxes: [
        {
          id: 'y-axis-0',
          display: 'auto',
          position: 'left'
        },
        {
          id: 'y-axis-1',
          display: 'auto',
          position: 'right',
          gridLines: {
            color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.3)',
          },
          ticks: {
            fontColor: 'red',
          }
        },        
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because they didn't update the typings of the library.

Consider opening an issue on their repo.

In the meantime, you can just

```
display: 'auto' as any,
```

To bypass that issue.